# Convert QString into unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring, unsigned-char

I have a very basic question here. I tried googling for a while, because there are a lot of similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me.

here is a code snippet that shows the problem:

```
QString test = "hello";
unsigned char* test1 = (unsigned char*) test.data();
unsigned char test2[10];
memcpy(test2,test1,test.size());
std::cout<<test2;
```

I try to fit the QString into the unsigned char array but 
the output I get is always just 'h'.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Note that a QChar is a 16-bit thing, storing a Unicode codepoint. For an 'h' (any US-ASCII) the high order byte will be 0. This explains why your output only shows 'h'.

Comment: @laune Thank you. I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is in that `QString.data()` returns a `QChar*` but you want `const char*`

```
QString test = "hello";
unsigned char test2[10];
memcpy( test2, test.toStdString().c_str() ,test.size());
test2[5] = 0;
qDebug() << (char*)test2;
             ^^^
            this is necessary becuase otherwise
            just address is printed, i.e. @0x7fff8d2d0b20
```

The assignment

```
unsigned char* test1 = (unsigned char*) test.data();
```

and trying to copy

```
unsigned char test2[10];
memcpy(test2,test1,test.size());
```

is wrong, because [`QChar` is 16 bit entity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#details) and as such trying to copy it will terminate because of 0 byte just after `'h'`.

Comment: thank you! It works perfectly, just what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 3):

In the second line you're trying to cast `QChar*` to `(unsigned char*)` which is completely wrong.

Try this:

```
QString test = "hello";
QByteArray ba = test.toLocal8Bit();
unsigned char *res = (unsigned char *)strdup(ba.constData());
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

Comment: OP: Unless you really need the result to be mutable, don't `strdup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Russian sims in the text that is written in the QString, then use this method.

```
unsigned char* temp;
QString name = "М102";
QByteArray ba = name.toUtf8();
temp = (unsigned char*)ba.data();
```